# Getting an error with ajax-request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make a like/dislike ability on my web application but I get errors here:

1) Like/dislike increments by 2 per ONE click
2) The request is sent, it updates the like/dislike variable, but I have to reload the page to see the new updated data.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here's my code:**

**My view:**

```
#app/views/dashboard/view.html.erb 
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up likeAction"><%=  p.like %> </td>
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down dislikeAction"><%= p.dislike %> </td>
```

**My controller:**

```
#app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb 
  def like
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.increment!(:like)
  end

  def dislike
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.increment!(:dislike)
  end
```

**My JS file:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".likeAction").click(function(){
    var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(){
          $("#likeAction").hide().fadeIn();
        }
     });
  });

  $(".dislikeAction").click(function(){
    var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/dislike',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(){
          $(".dislikeAction").hide().fadeOut();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

So it doesn't hide and then doesn't fade in.

Comment: Your `url` option, should be a relative, not an absolute, instead of `'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/'+ ....` use `/dashboard/' + ....`, also post an error message, it's not clear from the code.

Comment: when i use an relative url, i become i rout like : /dashboard/29/11/like - where 29 is the id of User, and 11 is the id of post, but i only need the id of post to get it from the params, so i tried as you said, bu did not become a correct url. My error message ?  The Chrome console says that it is an External error(500),  but it updates the value from post.like or post.dislike, just doesn't show it at once

Comment: Not the chrome console, in the rails log file that related to the rails server.

Comment: It commit the chaging of the like/dislike value, but is writes that there's an external error(500) . After this it tells about the missing template(view), i do not think, that it is something special

Comment: it is special, your ajax works only on `success` response from the server, 500 it is not a success response. Add `head :ok` or `render :nothing => true, :status => 200`  after `@post.increment!`  in both actions. Also you are missing a dot in the second `ajax` `function $(".dislikeAction")`.

Comment: yup, it works now without an single error, but the problems remain: i must reload my page to see the updates and the values increment by 2 per one click!

Comment: i cant get what you mean by _i must reload my page to see the updates_.

Comment: Please use the english language. Your current javascript code just make an request to the rails and fade in\out elements, it has nothing to do with updates.

Comment: But it calls the like/dislike methods where i change the values, or is it not correctly ?

Comment: Yep, just call the method do not update the values. To update the values, you should write some js code. I suggest you to render `json` with new values from rails actions(there is incrementing), the values is available in the js callbacks `success: function(data){ ... }` there is `data` should contain rendered by rails json with values from like\dislike actions.

Comment: It calls the methods, and the methods change the values, am i not right ? Ok, when it's not corrent, could you advice me the corrent answer ? how can i update my values of like/dislike variables just using the ajax-request ?

Comment: Something like `render json: @post.to_json, :status => 200`.

Comment: I'm sorry, i do not understand it clearly. so it should look like this : success: function(data){ render json: @post.to_json, :status => 200 } ? or what ? whence do i get post in my js file

Comment: Checkout my answer, i post an example for you.

Comment: Why you deleted it ?

Comment: Do is resolve you problem? I can restore it if you upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Relaod the page when your request runs successfully(`location.reload();`):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".likeAction").click(function(){
    var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(){
          $(".likeAction").hide().fadeIn();
          location.reload();
        }
     });
  });

  $(".dislikeAction").click(function(){
    var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/dislike',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(){
          $(".dislikeAction").hide().fadeOut();
          location.reload();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Also, notice: `.likeAction` instead of `#likeAction` in the first function. Also, note `.dislikeAction` instead of `dislikeAction`.